# Strange Rigify Deformation

Tags: armature, rigify

My issue lies with a rig made from the Bird Rigify skeleton; everything is working well, but when I rotated the chest or hips to the right, the mesh twists crazily into itself. Rotating to the left works just fine.

[image: screenshot]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwjLl.jpg

[image]

Comment: I saw this happen due to wrong IK chains, is head and neck made into IK chain?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not sure. I subdivided a bone or two to extend the neck and positioned the rest of the bones experimentally. This was the first time I've added bones to Rigify as well, which I did for the mandibles. How can I check whether it's an IK chain or not?

Comment: Well I already did, there is some chain between bone on the top of the head and the chest part, however I am not sure if this is the case

Comment: my bet is that you've got a bone roll problem as a result of your subdivide, or you've accidentally introduced a constraint loop.

Comment: not  bone roll afaict.  probably a loop but I don't see it in a quick look.  I'll see if I have more time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display these 3 layers:

[image]

It will display these 3 bones, they look like one but they are actually overlaying, select them with the lasso:

[image]

As you can see if you enable the axis their default orientation is not consistent with the rest of the chain. Rotate them 180° (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> 180). Enable the *Pose Position*. As you can see it hasn't fixed everything but at least your neck isn't twisted anymore:

[image]